# Difference between OAuth2 and OAuth3?

Tags: java, oauth

Recently I have been asked to work on Oauth3. I have a basic understanding of how Oauth works. But want to learn what is the main difference with Oauth2 or improvement has been made in Oauth3. There are not enough articles to read about it.
I want to implement Oauth3 support for my application.

Answer (score 4):

I'm working on a standard which I've dubbed OAuth3.

It's not an official standard yet by any means, but it's the only OAuth3 that has any sort of implementation: https://oauth3.org

I've outlined the goals in these videos:

- [OAuth3 - Identity Strategies (Advanced: must know OIDC)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-KzhxGoWbo)
- [OAuth3 - Federated Scopes (Advanced: must know OIDC)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ivrnNapq3LE)

Other than that there is no such thing as OAuth3.